# Angular onChange doesn't trigger event.stopPropagation to prevent outer div's click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have two nested clicks the outer belongs to a div and a checkbox inside

[image]

When checkbox is clicked unfortunately it triggers outer div's click.

```
<div
  (click)="clickParent()"
  style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red"
>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="checkbox-1"
    (change)="clickChild($event); stopPropagation($event)"
  />
  <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
</div>
  clickParent() {
    console.log('Click parent');
  }
  stopPropagation(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  clickChild() {
    console.log('Click child');
  }
```

ClickParennt is being triggered on each checkbox click.How to prevent parent's method being clicked?
Sample stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zw7bze?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 solutions here. 1st: call stopPropagation on click

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="checkbox-1"
    (click)="stopPropagation($event)"
    (change)="clickChild()"
  />
```

2nd: filter out events where the checkbox is clicked in parent handler

```
clickParent(event) {
   if(event.target.id != 'checkbox-1') {
     console.log('Click parent');
   }
}
```

Comment: Great solution thank you very much